# Facebook API error to write on friends wall

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-wall

I tried to post on my friends wall using the facebook API. But I am getting the following  error. How do I solve this?

```
013-02-12 12:31:57.951 sample[50506:907] Error: HTTP status code: 403
2013-02-12 12:31:57.959 sample[50506:907] Error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Posting to friends' feed stopped working on Feb 6th 2013](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/14792062/posting-to-friends-feed-stopped-working-on-feb-6th-2013)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

facebook has removed the ability to post on friends wall using graph api from 6th feb,2013. checkout the official doc here http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/completed-changes/ under subsection **Removing ability to post to friends walls via Graph API** from February 6, 2013 changes

**update**

Alternatives you can try are

1. you may use [feed dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/) to post on friends wall, that will prompt your user and if that user confirms, it will get posted on friends wall.
2. if you don't want to prompt your user, then you can post on your user wall with their friends tagged in the post then those post will also appear in friends wall assuming friends approve the tag.

Comment: Thanks for your reply . . Kindly let me know is there any alternate solution to post in friends wall ..?

Comment: check the update for alternatives. these are also there in doc 6th feb changes doc.

Comment: Thanks it helps... I ll give a try and get you back if anything is not clear. thanks a lot..